# How to enable auto completion in Qt creator in Fakevim mode

Tags: vim, qt-creator

Auto completion become disable when I enable FakeVim mode in Qt creator !
Do someone have a solution to enable it in fakevim mode?
Thanks

Comment: No solution yet right?

Comment: @Dualinity ~> Fixed in new version. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem [has been fixed](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/source/7724bd467388f6ae3b8a4cbc8609f535a94a03f1%3adist/changes-2.7.0#L209) in new versions of **Qt Creator**. You can download it from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads) . Additionally you can switch between fakevim mode and normal mode with **ALT+V ALT+V**(Press ALT+V 2 times )

Comment: I've got Qt Creator 2.7.0 and completion still doesn't work when using FakeVim.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone curious how to do this:

-For autocompletion, just use CTRL-SPACE to activate (then the usual selection method, CTRL-n forward, CTRL-p backward, etc.)

Comment: The problem is that this is not automatic, I have to press almost always the C-space. Though better than nothing.